# SQL to calculate number of tasks open at a given time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a nice query that calculates how many tasks have been opened and closed in a given week that works a charm, but I'm having difficulties extending it so that it can show me how many tasks we're still open at the end of that week.

In my mind, the sql will need to count the total number of issues that have been opened from the beginning of time, up to that week and then do the same for the number of closed and subtract the two from each other but with my limited knowledge of SQL, I'm struggling how to write this as it falls outside of the group by clause.

This is the SQL that I have:

```
SELECT  ISNULL(A.[Year],B.[Year]) [Year],
        ISNULL(A.[Week],B.[Week]) [Week],
        ISNULL(A.Opened,0) Opened,
        ISNULL(B.Closed,0) Closed,
A.totResponse, A.totCompletion
FROM (  SELECT  YEAR(insert_time) [Year],
                DATEPART(WEEK,insert_time) [Week],
                COUNT(id) Opened, sum(timer2) totResponse, sum(timer3) AS totCompletion
        FROM service_req
        WHERE [insert_time] IS NOT NULL and sr_type=1
        GROUP BY YEAR(insert_time), DATEPART(WEEK,insert_time)) A
FULL JOIN ( SELECT  YEAR(close_time) [Year],
                    DATEPART(WEEK,close_time) [Week],
                    COUNT(id) Closed
            FROM service_req 
            WHERE [close_time] IS NOT NULL and sr_type=1
            GROUP BY YEAR(close_time), DATEPART(WEEK,close_time)) B
    ON A.[Year] = B.[Year] AND A.[Week] = B.[Week]
ORDER BY [Year], [Week]
```

If there's anyone that could help me with this, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the count of tasks opened and not closed in a time frame or all tasks with are open in the time frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What would really make this query easier is a cumulative sum, which alas is introduced in SQL Server 2012.  In this case, you can emulate it using `row_number()`, because you want the cumulative count.

So, the idea is to calculate the cumulative number of opens and closes and then do the aggregation.  The `max()` of the cumulative numbers will be the number at the end of the week.  In thinking about this, I've rewritten the query using a `union all` rather than a `full outer join`:

```
with oc as (
      SELECT cast(insert_time as date) as thedate, 1 as opened, NULL as closed,
             timer2 as Response, timer3 as Completion,
             row_number() over (order by insert_time) as cumopened, NULL as cumclosed
      FROM service_req
      WHERE insert_time IS NOT NULL and sr_type = 1
      union all
      SELECT cast(close_time as date), NULL as opened, 1 as closed,
             NULL as Response, NULL as Completion,
             NULL as cumopened, row_number() over (order by close_time) as cumclosed
      FROM service_req
      WHERE close_time IS NOT NULL and sr_type = 1
     )
select year(thedate) as [Year],
       datepart(week, thedate) as [Week],
       coalesce(sum(opened), 0) as Opened, coalesce(sum(closed), 0) as closed,
       max(Response) as Response, max(Completion) as completion,
       coalesce(max(cumopened), 0) - coalesce(max(cumclosed), 0) as stillopened
from oc
group by year(thedate), datepart(week, thedate)
order by year(thedate), datepart(week, thedate);
```

You could actually rewrite your query using the same idea, just with a subquery to calculate the cumulative numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using SQL2008, the count rows would have been very nice!! I have also been looking at using an OVER clause, but struggling to understand that at the minute. When I run your query I receive this message: All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.